# unable to send multiple bcc mail

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send Bcc mail .My mail function is working for single mail but when I am trying for bcc mail then I  nothing happen .help me for possible solution .

```
    <?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //$to = "example@com"; // this is your Email address
    $to = "example@com";
    $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $first_name = $_POST['name'];
    $last_number = $_POST['number'];
    $last_query = $_POST['query'];
    $last_state = $_POST['state'];

    $subject = "Form submission";
    $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
    $message = $first_name . " " . $last_name ." ".$last_number." ". $last_query." ".$last_state." ". " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender
    echo $mag="Mail Sent. Thank you " . $first_name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
    // You can also use header('Location: thank_you.php'); to redirect to another page.
    }
?>
```

Comment: You are not trying to go live with this code, are you?

Comment: too late @AniketSahrawat. ;)

Comment: There is no bcc header in your code. Are you referring to the second `mail` call with "from" and "to" switched as "bcc"?

Comment: 1) Use PHPMailer or Swift Mailer, not PHP’s `mail`. 2) Stop the utter nonsense of trying to send the mail as _From_ the address that was entered in the form - this will massively increase the probability that receiving mail servers will classify your mail as spam.

Comment: There is no evidence that you have tried to implement `BCC`. Why don't you updated the question to "How to implement BCC"

Comment: CBroe@yes   itried to use php maile but currently getting issue so Iam doing this . becouse its urgent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send `Bcc` in headers only like below:

`headers .= "Bcc: addess1,addess2,etc \r\n";`

Answer (score 0):

you should try this format. also there is no bcc in your code

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\\r\ ";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\\r\ ";
$headers .= 'To: test <test@example.com>, test1 <test1@example.com>' . "\\r\ ";
$headers .= 'From: test3 <test3@example.com>' . "\\r\ ";
$headers .= 'Cc: [email]test4@example.com[/email]' . "\\r\ ";
$headers .= 'Bcc: [email]test5@example.com,test6@myserver.com,test7@gmail.com,test8@email.com[/email]' . "\\r\ ";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Bilal Ahmed@can you include this with my question .please

Comment: simply you can concatenate variable with email. example: replce  `test@example.com` with `$to`